# Question about Energy intensity, scale length for energy absorption

Tags: energy, particle-physics

I am a Yr 12 high school student and I am writing a report about space-based particle-beam weapon for my open project assessment.

I found a paper published in Nature. When talking about energy must be provided by particle acceleration, the author wrote this:
[image]

E=εlA

My question is that what the name of this formula is.
Also, I could find little information about "scale length for energy absorption". I will appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the name to search for more about the topic. Also, the line **the distance over which the beam particles are degraded in energy to ... Of their original value** means that the damage inflicted is not  linear, if you plotted damage against energy used you would get a graph of a curve that starts high on the y  axis but never touches the x axis, maybe you know this already though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this formula will have a universal name, but I can give some insight about the parameters.

### $l$ is very close to Radiation length, $X_0$.

$$
l = E\frac{dz}{dE}
$$

For beams of electrons or photons, the relevant material characteristic is called Radiation Length. In [Chapter 33 (Passage of Particles Through Matter)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2016-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf) of The Review of Particle Physics by the Particle Data Group they define Radiation length as

> High-energy electrons predominantly lose energy in matter by bremsstrahlung, and high-energy photons by $e^+ e^−$ pair production. The characteristic amount of matter traversed for these related interactions is called the radiation length $X_0$, usually measured in g cm${}^{-2}$. It is both (a) the mean distance over which a high-energy electron loses
>   all but $1/e$ of its energy by bremsstrahlung, and (b) $\frac{7}{9}$ of the mean free path for pair production by a high-energy photon.  It is also the appropriate scale length for describing high-energy electromagnetic cascades.

So their description of $X_0$ is very close to the text's descripton of $l$
A common quantity used in physics is  $\frac{dE}{dx}$, which is simply, the rate at which energy is deposited in the material ($dE$, amount of energy, $dx$ small distance). This is a property of the material that you are hitting but depends on the type and energy of the particle beam.

As shown in the below image, they describe 
$$
\frac{1}{l} = \frac{1}{E}\frac{dE}{dx}
$$
as the fractional energy loss per radiation length

[image: PDG 32.11]

As for the equation, I believe is simply the volume multiplied by an energy density of the beam. $E = \epsilon V= \epsilon lA$

Hope that is helpful!

Comment: You can close the question by accepting this as the answer. it helps the site.